# Why does xgboost.QuantileDMatrix do four passes of the data with custom data iterator?

Tags: python, machine-learning, parallel-processing, xgboost, quantile

I am trying to use a custom data iterator as shown [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/examples/quantile_data_iterator.html) since my dataset is too large. Just to test out how this works I am working with a subset of my example and running the following code. `X` is a numpy array of my data.

My iterator looks as follows

```
class IterForQDMatrix(xgb.core.DataIter):
    def __init__(self, df, batch_size):
        self.df = df
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.batches = np.ceil(len(df) // self.batch_size)
        self.it = 0
        super().__init__()
        
    def reset(self):
        self.it = 0
        
    def next(self, input_data):
        if self.it == self.batches:
            print("done")
            return 0
        a = self.it * self.batch_size
        b = min((self.it + 1) * self.batch_size, len(self.df))
        input_data(data=self.df[a:b, : -1], label=self.df[a:b, -1])
        self.it += 1
        return 1

iterator = IterForQDMatrix(X, 30)
xgb_data = xgb.QuantileDMatrix(iterator)
```

When I run the above code I notice that `"done"` is printed four times, implying that when I pass my iterator to `xgb.QuantileDMatrix`, it passes over the entire dataset four times. I am trying to understand why it is passing over the data four times. Is there a way to achieve whatever it is doing in just one pass of the data?